# Permissions To Update Legacy DTS Packages

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, dts

I am trying to grant access to allow users to view and update existing legacy DTS packages. The problem is that they cannot see the needed nodes under Management to begin working on them. I've tried granting every possible permission, including making them db_owners of the MSDB but nothing so far has worked. If I grant CONTROL at the server level the nodes become visible but this is certainly not a sustainable set of permissions.

Attached are 2 images. One of the nodes as I see them as one as they seem them. I've prowled around the web trying to identify the minimum rights needed but have so far not come up with the right formula.

Does anyone know what the minimum rights for this process are or am I stuck making them temporary super-users?

This is what I see

[image: My View]

This is what they see

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way we were able to find a way around this was to grant the user SysAdmin rights. Even with CONTROL at the server level, it is not available.